# How To: Query & Display items from ALL lists within a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, caml-query, caml

I am looking to query and display items from all of the lists that exist (and will exist in the future) on a specific subsite (SP 2013).

Below is what I have so far but it is not producing any alert, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var siteUrl = '/mysite/mysubsite';

function retrieveAllListProperties() {

    //var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    //var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    //this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    //clientContext.load(collList);

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

    this.listInfoCollection = clientContext.loadQuery(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var listInfo = '';

    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + 
args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script 
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var siteUrl = '/mysite/mysubsite';

// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase =  siteUrl  + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
        }
    );
});

// Function to execute basic operations.
function execOperation() {

    // Continue your program flow here.
    retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl);

}

function retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    this.listInfoCollection = clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listInfo = '';

    var listEnumerator = this.collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me. Suppose I need to add a filter so that only certain lists are displayed, could I add that to the onQuerySucceeded?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use Search Rest api for this requirement, query so many lists would increase large number of requests to server.

To use search rest api in add-in.

You could check [MSDN guideline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/search-add-ins-in-sharepoint) or [GithHub demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint-Add-in-REST-SearchAPIs).

To get all listitems by search rest api(may need paging based on your data volume).

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentClass="STS_ListItem"'
```

More about ContentClass property

http://avalagopi767.blogspot.com/2016/02/sharepoint-2013-keyword-query-kql.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to register another delegated execution in your onQuerySucceeded() to retrieve list items for each list. Haven't tried, but might work

```
function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var listInfo = '';

    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';

        retrieveListItems(oList)
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}

function retrieveListItems(oList) {


    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>' //or whatever criteria you want
    );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded2), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed2)
    ); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded2(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed2(sender, args) {
    alert('Request list items failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

You can also do this using Promises, async/await calls to the REST API if u like.

```
[siteUrl]/_api/web/webs (to get subsites)
[subwebs(n)Url]/_api/web/lists (to get subweb  lists)
[subwebs(n)Url]/_api/web/lists/getbyid(guid'[list(n)guid]')/items (to get subweb list listItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve your requirement by using Content Query web part, which will query the specified URL for all list items.

Configuration details available here - [Content Query WP COnfiguration](https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Publishing-Infrastructure-Content-Query.htm)